# Inner join order does matter in my query

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

First Query

```
select name, letters, date, count(p.playernumber) as data 
from players p inner join fines f using(playernumber) 
group by playernumber
```

Second Query

```
select name, letters, date, count(p.playernumber) as data 
from fines f inner join players p using(spelersnr) 
group by playernumber
```

the first query is not able to run while second query is. I thought the order of inner join didn't matter? How come the second query is able to run because I thought every column in the select (except aggregations) has to be in the group by?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting.  This is due to a Postgres supporting using primary and unique keys in the `group by` clause and then allowing columns associated with each key to be in the `select` with no aggregation functions.  The ANSI standard supports this.

The issue is that `spelersnr` is ambiguous -- it could come from either table.  I guess Postgres defaults to the first table for parsing the query.  When the column is the primary key, then it is fine (because `naam` etc. come from that table).  When the column is not a primary key, then it you get the error.

The solution is simply:

```
group by s.spelersnr
```

I would expect Postgres to issue an error like "`spelersnr` is ambiguous" -- meaning it doesn't know what table it is coming from.  If you used an `on` clause instead of a `using` clause, you should get such an error for both queries.